# li text not using whole width

Tags: css

i have a ul, with three li inside it. the first li text is "opptakskrav" and the last li element is "ja". Anyone know why the text on my second li doesnt use the whole width and why it starts a new line halfway?

[image]

```
<ul class="admission infoUl">
     <li class="head">Opptakskrav</li>
     <li>Kravet for opptak til bachelorgraden er normalt generell studiekompetanse.</li>
     <li> ja</li>
</ul>
```

this is the only css:

```
.infoUl {
      padding-left:35px;
 }

 .infoUl li.head  {
      font-weight:bold;
 }
```

Comment: note: class admission only gives the ul a background image, nothing else...

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fPNha/. Are you sure something isn't limiting the space it resides in?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a width set on the *ul* or *li*. Maybe a style is being inherited from a different stylesheet. Is there another set of styles that is making the text sans-serif with a grey background?

Comment: thanks! there was indeed something setting a width for the ul so setting the width to 100% solved the problem